# Alternative for returning an array from a property getter

Tags: c#

I'm wondering why Code Analysis (in VS 2012) emits "CA1819: Properties should not return arrays" for the following code:

```
private byte[] BackingFieldData;

public byte[] Data
{
    get { return this.BackingFieldData; }
    set { this.BackingFieldData = value; }
}
```

The description of the warning states *Arrays returned by properties are not write-protected, even if the property is read-only. To keep the array tamper-proof, the property must return a copy of the array.*

What i want is to return the array. The user should be able to modify the array, but should not be able to resize it. The size of the array is frequently accessed by the user. The user must be able to access the elements by index. Therefore the array type seems to fit perfectly.

Alternates I've considered are `IEnumerable<byte>` (Indexing is awfully done using `Skip` and `Take` etc.), `IList<byte>` (which focuses on adding and removing elements - I don't want that) and `ReadOnlyCollection<byte>` (I hate it when classes expose methods which  always throw `NotSupportedException`s, far away from good coding style IMHO). I also thought about creating a custom Interface with a wrapper class around the array - but what's the point in that (except that I could get rid of the warning without suppressing it).

So, does anyone know about a good type to return instead of an array type or of a good reason why not to return an array in this case? Are there any implications I did not mention so far?

Answer (score 5):

In this case, you should suppress that warning.
Most array guidelines do not apply to `byte[]`s.

However, you should also remove (or `private`ize) the setter.

Comment: +1 for `privatize` :D (Also because it's a good point if they shouldn't be allowed to change the length.)

Comment: +1 public setter is a mistake I see all the time with any collection type.

Comment: Sorry, 5 lines of code and already a bug ;-) . There is no setter at all in my implementation. Only in the demo code; I wanted to see if the warning also occurs if there is setter available...

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework 4.5 provides the [IReadOnlyList<T> Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385.aspx)

Arrays can be assigned to a `IReadOnlyList<T>` without conversion etc. - IMHO the best solution.

Comment: I don't get it. How is this a solution? In the question you say "The user should be able to modify the array". But this can't be done through the `IReadOnlyList` interface.

Comment: @Henrik: You are completely right; I've started to use `IReadOnlyList<T>`to get rid of the warning in cases where the user does not need to modify the content. I've found no solution for my initial problem yet.